# How to process a plain text file using the Azure Cognitive Services Text-to-Speech REST API and Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, text-to-speech

I'm trying to process a plain text file to create a wav audio file using Azure Cognitive Services Text-to-Speech REST API and Powershell. I don't understand how to do that instead of directly adding the content (specifically in `$Content`) to the script and how to use a custom lexicon in the process. I removed part of the script (auth) to simplify. Thanks.

```
$AudioOutputType='audio-24khz-96kbitrate-mono-mp3'

$XSearchAppID='000000000000000000000'

$XSearchClientID='00000000000000000000000'

$UserAgent='PowerShellTextToSpeechApp'

$Header=@{ `

'Content-Type' = 'application/ssml+xml'; `

'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat' = $AudioOutputType; `

'X-Search-AppId' = $XSearchAppId; `

'X-Search-ClientId' = $XSearchClientId; `

'Authorization' = $AccessToken `

}

$Locale='es-MX'

$ServiceNameMapping='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (es-MX, DaliaNeural)'

$Content='\path\Test.txt'

$Body=''+$Content+''

$Endpoint= 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize'

$Method='POST'

$ContentType='application/ssml+xml'

$Filename='output.wav'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Endpoint -Method $Method `

-Headers $Headers -ContentType $ContentType `

-Body $Body -UserAgent $UserAgent `

-OutFile $Filename
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding the exact API documentation you are using, but based off what I found in the below Azure Cog. Service docs...

[How to Synthesize Speech from Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-speech-synthesis?tabs=browserjs%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-rest#Synthesize%20Speech%20to%20A%20File)

[Deploy and use your voice model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-deploy-and-use-endpoint?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

You may be able to splat together the XML format, which it appears to need in the Body of the API REST request, and your text file content. Perhaps something like this to get your $Content variable.

```
$xmlStart = @'
<speak version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice xml:lang="en-US" xml:gender="Female" name="en-US-JennyNeural">
'@

$Content = Get-Content -Path [Path to your text file]

$xmlEnd = @'
    </voice>
</speak>
'@

$ContentToSpeak = $xmlStart + $Content + $xmlEnd
```

Haven't used Azure Cognitive Text-to-Speech yet, so this is just a best guess  not knowing your chosen API docs.

**EDIT:** Think I found it. Looks like here is where you got your docs.

[Windows PowerShell and the Text-to-Speech REST API (Part 3)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/windows-powershell-and-the-text-to-speech-rest-api-part-3/)

Here is Part #4 with the XML Content.

[Windows PowerShell and the Text-to-Speech REST API (Part 4)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/windows-powershell-and-the-text-to-speech-rest-api-part-4/)